# Directing to google maps from website with current location for user

Tags: c#, google-maps, mobile

I was really struggling to make a title for this one. I hope it's okay.

I have a website with several office-locations. I would like to send the user to google maps with the location of the selected office, and i would also like to use the location of the user.

This website is for mobiles only.

I've done some research, and I've found one possible method to do this, but i cant' but wonder, there has to be an easier way to do this. Using a whole lot of code to see which language the users browser is, and then pass on "Current+Location" into the href in the correct language seems weird considering its Google.

I'm using the following href right now, where i will be adding a dynamic location for the offices.

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=CURRENTLOCATION&daddr=OFFICELOCATION&hl=en&geocode=Ff7kxwMdn62eAClBW-CUmzFtRjG-TdPYIg6PMw%3BCVVCpEO5eoJYFdnnxwMd5LKeACEJ5__6cDooDym1URz6mzFtRjFiK54FolriNQ&mra=pe&mrcr=0&dirflg=w&doflg=ptm&sll=63.408475,10.396459&sspn=0.102044,0.33783&ie=UTF8&z=19
">Directions</a>
```

Its the CURRENTLOCATION I'm not getting a hang on how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most smartphones have HTML 5 browsers.  You can utilize the HTML 5 Geolocation spec to retrieve the users current position.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Then either send the lat/long directly to google maps, or do a reverse geocode look up using  google maps rest api's.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: So, this helped me a lot, and i'm now able to get the directions. I do however have another question.

Is there any way to send in coords, and get back the distance? I'm going go have an ordered list of offices in meters away from the user. This is going to be before the user clicks to get the directions etc.

Comment: In fact there is also a rest api, provided by google for that too.  I think it will help you.   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Comment: So, i see there's a possibility to use the following url:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=nb-NO&sensor=false

but, how can i get the information into my javascript to actually use? I gotta parse it to json or?

Comment: You could call the rest API from your server side code. It's just a get request. Or you could also the distance calculation yourself on the server side, as long as you know that starting and ending lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend opening the native app from your web app, I have a client that wants that and it is a terrible experience. You also don't have good control over the results and of course you are forcing the user to leave your web app, which means they probably wont come back.

I think a lot of folks don't think they can use the maps in their web app, but you absolutely can and it works great. The code is no different than if you were on the desktop.

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2012/05/25/A-Study-Using-The-HTML5-Geolocation-API.aspx